# Cache not refreshing when requested

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, caching, rxjs

I'm working on a project that is not caching as expected. I have services that accept a `boolean` option called `refresh`. When it is set to true the service gets the value from the API, when it is set to false it retrieves the value from a cached set. However when I set the refresh option to true, the application does make an API request but still returns the cached value and not the value returned by the API. Anyone know what could be going on?

```
if (needsRefresh) {
  let firstRun = true;
  return Observable.if(
    () => {
      if (firstRun) {
        firstRun = false;
        return true;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
   },
   this.requestSet(key, where).switchMap(() => this._cachedSets.get(key)),
                this._cachedSets.get(key)
   );
 }
 else {
   return this._cachedSets.get(key);
 }
```

Comment: May I see your cache service?

Comment: This depends on the implementation. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is necessary here.

Comment: Before asking new questions, please also take the time to give feedback and / or mark answers as accepted in your previous questions. Leaving people without any feedback can (and will, in my case) impact the amount of answers you get.